# Read from csv first word and word first word after v

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am wanting to read from csv, put it into dataframe and get the very first word and first word after v.

Csv to dataframe looks like:

```
       A
0 choclate v dairy cakes
1 ice cake v ka ka1
2 cc dd v ee fff gg hh
3 iii  v kkkk
```

Desired:

```
   A
0 choclate v dairy
1 ice v ka 
2 cc v ee
3 iii  v kkkk
```

I try:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('C:\\THE.csv',
                  index_col=False,
                  usecols=[0],
                  names=["AA"],
                  header=None)
zz = df1['AA'].str.split('v', expand=True)\
  .apply(lambda x: x.str.extract('(\w+)', expand=False))\
  .apply(lambda x: ' v '.join(x), 1)
```

Error:

```
    .apply(lambda x: ' v '.join(x), 1)
TypeError: ('sequence item 1: expected str instance, float found', 'occurred at index 1')
```

How can I get my desired output?

Comment: Is that 0 1 2 3 inside the A column or is that in the index of your dataframe?

Comment: @ScottBoston Index of dataframe

Comment: I think it is same with your previous question

Comment: I didn't reproduce your error.  but you can try to change the last line  to `.apply(lambda x: ' v '.join(x.astype(str)), 1)`

Comment: @ScottBoston I think that might of done the trick.  Will re-test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
df.A.str.split(' v ').apply(lambda x : [y.split(' ')[0] for y in x]).apply(' v '.join)
Out[198]: 
0    choclate v dairy
1            ice v ka
2             cc v ee
3          iii v kkkk
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Comment: For my full data this works inconsistently. I can link file if you like

Comment: @gerrybro can you provide the row did not work ? I think only one example will be enough

Comment: Nothing is changed at all for my csv actually

Comment: @gerrybro that is interesting , maybe add a add a picture for your csv?

Comment: User related errors :).  It's working as expected now

Comment: @gerrybro ah, happy coding :-)